# How to remove \002 char in ruby

Tags: ruby

How do I remove the \002 char that has appeared in my string in ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string.delete!("\002")
```

or

```
string.delete("\002")
```

if you don't want in-place modification.

Answer (score 0):

The method is called `kind_of?`, including the question mark, not `kind_of`.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for the answer, but that's not the actual question. Edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using gsub -

```
myString.gsub(/\W+/, '')
```

Any better way of doing this?

Comment: why not just myString.gsub!(/\\002/, '')